# .htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, relative-urls

I am trying to make my url from this:

```
example.com/view.php?id=15
```

To this:

```
example.com/watch/15
```

My code in `.htaccess` is as follows:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^watch/([^/]+) view.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Now if I go to `example.com/watch/15` it loads the content but without any JS, CSS because in this case it looks for CSS and JS under the `/watch` folder which doesn't exist.

How do I make this option work properly? I don't want to create watch folder and copy-paste CSS and JS so it will embed properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not being able to find your JavaScript and CSS files is a client-side/browser issue related to your URL-path, it's not something that should be fixed in `.htaccess` (at least not in this case) - although it is because you are changing this URL-path (in `.htaccess`) that you are experiencing this problem.

This problem is caused by using relative URLs in your HTML. Relative to what? Remember, it is the user-agent/browser that resolves relative URLs in your HTML, not the server. So, you need to fix your URLs; not `.htaccess`.

For example, if you are referencing your CSS file with a *relative* URL of the form `href="styles.css"` (note, no slash prefix) and you are currently at the URL `example.com/view.php?id=15` then the *browser* will naturally resolve your CSS URL and request `example.com/styles.css` (in the document root). However, if you are currently at the URL `example.com/watch/15` (effectively in a `/watch` "subdirectory" <sup>**[*1]**</sup>) then the *browser* will resolve your *relative* CSS URL *relative* to a `/watch` subdirectory, rather than the document root, so you end up with an absolute/resolved URL of the form `example.com/watch/styles.css`.

(<sup>**[*1]**</sup> Note that "subdirectory" in this context is not necessarily a physical subdirectory on your server - it is a "subdirectory" in the URL-path; an additional path-segment. But the browser does not know the difference.)

The same applies if you are using relative URLs in your custom error documents (defined with the `ErrorDocument` directive on Apache). The custom error document can potentially be called on any URL, so any relative URL to a static resource (CSS, image, JS, etc.) is going to be relative to the URL that caused the error, not relative to the error document itself (the location of which is effectively hidden from the user-agent).

If you changed your JavaScript and CSS URLs to be root-relative (starting with a slash) or even absolute then you would not get this problem. This would be the preferred method. Alternatively, you can use the `base` element...

### `base` tag/element

Alternatively you can include a `base` element in the `head` section of your HTML document (although this is not without its caveats <sup>**[*2]**</sup>). This references the absolute URL that all relative URLs are *relative* to. In other words, since you are expecting these relative URLs to be relative to the document root then add the following to the `head` section:

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

Now, a relative URL such as `styles.css` referenced in a document at URL `/watch/15` will request `http://example.com/styles.css`, not `http://example.com/watch/styles.css`.

<sup>**[*2]**</sup> There are, however, some caveats with using the `base` element. A primary concern is that any *relative* URL that is intended to target the *current* document will now target the base URL instead. This can effect in-page anchors like `href="#top"` and URLs of the form `href="?sortby=date"` etc. And also `form` elements that submit to themselves using an empty `action` attribute (eg. `<form action="" ...`). These relative URLs that target the current document will need to be modified to include the full URL of the current page (which may defeat the point of using the `base` tag as a *workaround* to begin with).

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/what-are-the-recommendations-for-html-base-tag

Comment: Yes it works once I add base in the head section. I wasted 2h trying to work it out and yet its simple as adding 1 line of code...
Many thanks for your informative answer!