# Writing clean urls with .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, url-rewriting, url-parameters, clean-urls

**Update** - Alright thanks everyone for your tests, it really helped. The code is good. My problem was not having absolute "/" links. (Due to moving from public_html folder).

Only 2 concerns i have now.

1.) Replace "^achilles" with "^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)" and thumbnails wont appear (parameter data is not being carried???)

2.) How can I make http://funkygames.co/games/achilles/achilles/1 become even shorter like http://funkygames.co/games/achilles Or are the parameters absolutely mandatory.

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on     

# Set the base to /games/ so we need not include it in the rules
RewriteBase /games/

#Rewrite for achilles.php?games_path=xxxxxxxxxx.yyy&category_id=zzz
RewriteRule ^achilles/(.*)/([0-9]+) $1.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

---

Where i learned: www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pbAV6AU99I

---

**SOLVED!** Thanks to you guys. 
Solution:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on     

# Set the base to /games/ so we need not include it in the rules
RewriteBase /games/

#Rewrite for achilles.php?games_path=xxxxxxxxxx.yyy&category_id=zzz
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) $1.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

http://funkygames.co/games/achilles/1

Comment: A problem you have with your site is that you are using relative URLs to images, CSS and JS. When you change the URL structure you are changing what these resources/URLs are relative to and so they cannot be found. So, even if your internal rewrite "works", your site is still going to break. See this answer for more information: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243

Comment: Thank you. This was the main problem. Not having "/" infront of directories. I now have: "http://funkygames.co/games/achilles/achilles/1"   Is there anyway I can make it "http://funkygames.co/games/achilles" or is it a MUST that I include these parameters? I tried to replace achilles.php with something dynamic like ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) but for some reason it wouldnt carry the "category_id" information unless i went static.

Comment: #Rewrite for achilles.php?games_path=xxxxxxxxxx.yyy&category_id=zzz

RewriteRule ^achilles/(.*)/([0-9]+) $1.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]`

Comment: Any parameters you _need_ in the rewritten URL must be present in the original URL - so it depends on what your application expects. In your question you have `/games/achilles/1` - this looks doable, however, in your comment you are missing what would be the `category_id` - presumably you do need the category ID, or can it be omitted?

Comment: Id rather have "games/achilles/1" But it appears that I need "games/achilles/achilles/1" due to the name of the .swf file. I dont mind keeping that category id. But if i could simplify this to just "games/game-title/category-id" rather than "games/game-title/game-title.swf/category-id" that would be perfect.

Comment: `#Rewrite for achilles.php?games_path=xxxxxxxxxx.yyy&category_id=zzz
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) $1.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]`

Comment: Alright I've done that. Im assuming that gives you researching points? I've found that documenting the solutions to problems really helps. Because in time its possible to forget the solutions and you run into the same problem you just fixed last month! lol

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED! Thanks to you guys. Solution:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on     

# Set the base to /games/ so we need not include it in the rules
RewriteBase /games/

#Rewrite for achilles.php?games_path=xxxxxxxxxx.yyy&category_id=zzz
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) $1.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

http://funkygames.co/games/achilles/1

If your website is appearing but its not showing pictures or dynamic database content. Then you must make sure you use absolute links

"/this-is-absolute"(will work from any folder) 
"this-relative"(will only work from public_html)

Answer (score 2):

> I have: http://funkygames.co/games/achilles.php?games_path=achilles.swf&category_id=1
>
> I want: http://funkygames.co/games/achilles/achilles/1 or even better: funkygames.co/games/achilles/1 (if that's possible)

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^games/achilles/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /games/achilles.php?games_path=$1.swf&category_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

And if the game name needs to be case sensitive, remove the NC from `[NC,L]`.

Comment: If this .htaccess file is in the `/games` directory then you'll need to remove `games/` from the start of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. (Optional: You could also remove the `/games/` prefix from the _substitution_.)