# htaccess Redirect everything to index.php little trouble

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I need to redirect everything (`www.example.com/`, `www.example.com/en/`, `www.example.com/en/index.php?do=xyz`, etc.) to `index.php`, but I can't get everything working.

**1st try:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

works, but stylesheets `href="css/xyz.css"` don't load if I use `www.example.com/en/`. I would need to change them to `href="/css/xyz.css"` and I won't.

**2nd try:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*) $2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?op=$1 [L,NS,QSA]
```

This works, CSS files are ok, the only bad thing is that **jquery $.get** can't find the files so I think I am missing something on the way.
And maybe I could do everything using only one `RewriteRule`?

Any suggestion?

Comment: You might also be able to use the `base` element to get around relative URL problems to your static resources. See also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243

Answer (score 2):

After some trys and searches I got it working using:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+)$ /$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Isn't that always the way? You fiddle around with something forever, finally give up and post a question, then figure it out afterwards. We have all done this. It seems to be a necessary part of the process. I am glad you got it!!