# .htaccess redirect url to a subfolder on a subdomain with exceptions

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, subdomain

I have a CMS installed on a subdomain (say `blog.domain.com`). I created a site on it but the site can be accessed at (`blog.domain.com/sites/mysite`). I also have to use other links like `blog.domain.com/#/create` and `blog.domain.com/#/login/mysite`

How do I achieve the following things:

1. Redirect all requests to `blog.domain.com` to `blog.domain.com/sites/mysite` WITHOUT changing the URL.
2. Still have access to `blog.domain.com/#/create` and `blog.domain.com/#/login/mysite`

I know there are a lot of answers on .htaccess redirects but I cant find the complete answer for both my questions above.

Answer (score 1):

In your *subdomains* document root, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/mysite/
RewriteRule (.*) sites/mysite/$1 [L]
```

Since this is an *internal rewrite*, you don't need to do anything with regards to #2

Comment: thanks for your response @DocRoot. There are two things that are happening:
1. The above rule redirects to `blog.domain.com/sites/mysite` but the url isn't changed. it should remain `blog.domain.com`
2. I am still unable to access `blog.domain.com/#/create`. It redirects me to `blog.domain.com/sites/mysite/#/create`

Comment: "but the url isn't changed" - I assume you mean "is changed"? Try clearing your browser cache. The above directive shouldn't be redirecting. The URL should not change. If you've been testing redirects (ie. `R=301`) then these will have been cached by the browser.

Comment: yep. i did that. no luck. i use chrome by default but i also used firefox and safari in this case to verify.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your .htaccess file? Is your subdomain stored in a subdirectory off the main domains document root, and this .htaccess file is in that subdirectory? Try removing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` substitution (I'll update the answer).

Comment: i cleared the cache again. that works partially. i see the site has been redirected but i get some javascript errors because its looking for a javascript file under the main directory instead of the `mysite` directory. and the second one doesnt work at all

Comment: That's probably because you are using relative URL-paths to your JavaScript files. See this other question to resolve this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css/86458 (Just to clarify, you are now seeing `blog.domain.com/#/create` in the browsers address bar I assume? This is an _internal rewrite_, not an _external redirect_. If you were _redirected_, you would see `/sites/mysite` in the address bar.)

Comment: thanks i will refer to the other question. and no i am not seeing `blog.domain.com/#/create` yet :(

Comment: Ah, if you are still being redirected, after removing the slash and clearing your browser cache then _something else_ would seem to be doing this. There could be a clash with other directives in .htaccess. The order is important.