# How to remove .jsp extension and replace with forward Slash in htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to remove the `.jsp` extension from my URL and replace it with a forward slash eg. `example.com/xyz.jsp` to `example.com/xyz/` and `example.com/xyz.jsp?ab=12` to `example.com/xyz/?ab=12`.

I used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

And

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /example.html to /example
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L]

# internal forward from /example/ to //example.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

In my `.htaccess` but neither are not working correctly.

Comment: Just to confirm, presumably you have already changed the URL you are linking to in your application to read `example.com/xyz/`? The first code block references `.php` extensions and the second `.html`, whereas you are using `.jsp` - so even without looking at the code it's clear they are not going to work? But anyway, when you say "not working correctly", please be specific... what happens _exactly_, an errors?

Comment: i'm sorry, i just pasted from the site i referred, i've given .jsp in place of .html and .php .... the problem i'm facing is if i pass url by removing .jsp with / it's throwing 404 erro e.g www.mywebsite.com/sompage.jsp if i give url as www.mywebsite.com/sompage/ then  it's not working. can u plz guide me over that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to ensure that `MultiViews` is disabled before this will work correctly, as this will tend to conflict with your mod_rewrite directives. Add this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

(`FollowSymLinks` needs to be enabled for mod_rewrite to work, so just to be sure.)

Then, something like what you already have looks reasonable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.jsp -f
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1.jsp [L]
```

I've made the trailing slash mandatory on the URL (otherwise you potentially have two URLs accessing the same content - duplicate content).

**UPDATE:** To redirect any requests to the `.jsp` URL to the canonical URL (ie. without the extension and with a trailing slash) then something like the following (similar to what you had in your question) would need to go *before* the directives above:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.jsp\s
RewriteRule (.+)\.jsp$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This is only strictly necessary if the `.jsp` URLs had been indexed or externally linked to. If this is a new site then this step is optional.

It is more efficient to match what you can with the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `(.+)\.jsp$`), rather than have a catch-all regex here. The `THE_REQUEST` condition ensures that this only applies to initial requests and not rewritten requests - thus preventing a redirect loop.

So, in summary:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Remove file extension from URLs (external redirect)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.jsp\s
RewriteRule (.+)\.jsp$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite extensionless URLs back to ".jsp"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.jsp -f
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1.jsp [L]
```

---

**DEBUGGING:** To help with debugging the above, add the following directive below the `RewriteEngine On` directive and check the environment variables (`MOD_REWRITE_THE_REQUEST` and `MOD_REWRITE_URL_PATH`) in your server-side code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=MOD_REWRITE_THE_REQUEST:%1,E=MOD_REWRITE_URL_PATH:$1]
```

What do these environment variables contain when you access a `.jsp` URL?

Comment: I have made all the necessary changes in my .htaccess that you have told. Still me facing the same issue.

Comment: 1- My website is accessible with both .jsp and with forward slash. 2- After using this htaccess code all my internal links are not working. Check out this link https://faadoocoupons.com/natures-basket-coupons-offers-1584.jsp  and https://faadoocoupons.com/natures-basket-coupons-offers-1584/  for more clarification.

Comment: The errors that you are seeing (missing CSS, JS and incorrect internal links) are caused by relative links in your HTML, not becuase of the `.htaccess` rules above (which seem to be working OK). See this other question for more information on the relative path issue: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: Thanks, That works great after using Base element in the Head section of my webpage. But My pages are accessible with both URL, Which can cause duplicate content problem. So how can i permanently redirect all my .jsp page to forward slash?

Comment: I've updated my answer with code to redirect from the `.jsp` URL to the canonical URL (ending in a slash). This is very similar to what you had initially, just with minor tweaks.

Comment: Still facing same Problem, having 2 Url for same content. I changed canonical url of my webpage ending with forward slash. and used the same code in htaccess that you have modified. Screen shot of htaccess http://prnt.sc/cfjmu4 . :(

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the additional code?

Comment: Which additional code you are talking about?

Comment: The code under **UPDATE:** in my answer: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.jsp\s` etc. (?)

Comment: M extremely sorry by mistake is removed that piece of code. Here's updated screen shot. check this out. http://prnt.sc/cfju5d Still duplicate content issue.

Comment: Ok, that's odd, that should work. There would seem to be something else going on here... what happens when a `.jsp` page is requested, is there a specific handler that handles this request? I'll add a code snippet to my answer to help debug this. Alternatively, you can also get around the duplicate content issue by setting a `rel="canonical"` meta tag or corresponding `Link:` HTTP response header.

Comment: ...a server-side caching issue perhaps?

Comment: No, there's no specific handler to handles the request. I added that debugging script on my .htaccess. which you can see http://prnt.sc/cfrf27 Now what i have to do, to know what's the real problem?

Comment: You would need to "check those environment variables (`MOD_REWRITE_THE_REQUEST` and `MOD_REWRITE_URL_PATH`) in your server-side code" ie. check the contents of those variables using whatever server-side language you are using (Java?). For that redirect not to occur it's possible that one of those server variables does not hold the information we are expecting - but we need to check.