# .htaccess mask redirect subdirectory to another subdirectory

Tags: htaccess, redirects, subdirectory

The URL of a page in my site is:

```
http:/mysite.com/one/two/three/four
```

I want to **mask** access this page via:

```
http:/mysite.com/fast/quick
```

The problem is within this page there are subfolders and, let's say, when I define a .js file in the index.html header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/mylib.js"></script>
```

It says file not found because it's looking for it in `/fast/quick`.

==> Remember the redirection must be masked, not direct.

Comment: How have you implemented the "mask access"? See also this related question: [.htaccess rewrite url leads to missing css](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the full URL?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:/mysite.com/lib/mylib.js"></script>
```

or even

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/mylib.js"></script>
```

One of the best ways to find your own answer is to experiment.

Comment: Tried. Not working. This works but it's a full redirect, no masking:
`RewriteRule ^ops/en?$ /course/en/accessible_ops$1 [R]`
I need masking :)

Comment: Plus there's a bunch of relative paths in this page. I don't want to have to rewrite them all as absolute paths.

Comment: when it doesn't work, what is the error in the console?  That will give you a clue on how to solve this.

Comment: Error in console is: anything with relative path is not found. If I type the absolute path it will work but this is what I'm trying to avoid. I want the URL to be masked but the site to act like if inside another subfolder.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but a kludge solution would be to hard code the javascript