# How to issue .htaccess for Laravel?

Tags: htaccess, apache2

I have just launched a Laravel 5.3 project on a live server and all is going well except one.

But my issue is, my websites are running on all 3 different URLs:

1. `example.com`
2. `example.com/public/index.php`
3. `example.com/<any-word>/index.php`

My `.htaccess` is: (This file is in the root folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I just want to see my website with `example.com` URL only.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to issue an external redirect before your existing directives. For example, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive, try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/index\.php(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache when testing.

The `RewriteCond` directive, checking against `REDIRECT_STATUS`, prevents a redirect loop after the internal rewrite at the end.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help me, but this code not work for me :-(

Comment: Don't load any CSS and JS file !

Comment: I've just corrected the regex in the above `RewriteRule`. However, as it was, it shouldn't have done anything?! Can you confirm that your site is functioning correctly without this directive when you access `example.com/`? Missing CSS and JS files are a client-side relative URL problem, see also my answer to this other question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243