# How to have .htaccess display 404.html for child pages

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, 404

I am working on a website `example.com` that has an error page `example.com/404.html`.

Here's my entire `.htaccess` file (Apache):

```
# Forces HTTPS

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

# 404 redirect

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# Disables directory indexing (being able to view a list of files instead of the actual webpage)

Options -Indexes
```

I'm using relative 404 so that it will display the content of the 404 error page without actually redirecting the user (and thereby changing the URL). This works great for upper level pages like `example.com/nonexistentpage.html`.

However, I am not sure how to handle child pages, like `example.com/parent/nonexistentpage.html`.

Currently, I have duplicated my existing `404.html` page, modified it with `../` in all the URL references so it looks for resources in the correct location, and put the new "child" `404.html` pages in each of my "parent" folders where there are child pages. When I access `example.com/parent/404.html`, the error page displays correctly with all styling and links where they should be. However, when I access `example.com/parent/nonexistentpage.html`, although the URL doesn't change, I get a generic, unstyled 404 error message instead of my custom `404.html` page.

Am I missing something/doing something wrong? The goal is for the error page content to display when accessing nonexistent child pages while not redirecting/changing the actual URL. I also tried commenting out `Options -Indexes`, but that had no effect.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything. You would normally serve the same `ErrorDocument` regardless of what URL caused the error. In your case, you are serving `/404.html` in the document root of your site.

However, it sounds as if you are using *relative* URLs to your static resources inside your error document. This is never going to work (unless you [set a `base` tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) - but this is not without its caveats - see *reference link* below) since the error document could be served from anywhere and so the *browser* will resolve your relative URLs incorrectly (or at least, not as you intended). Instead, you need to use root-relative URLs (starting with a slash, as you have done for `/404.html`) or absolute URLs (including scheme + hostname).

> when I access `example.com/parent/nonexistentpage.html`, although the URL doesn't change, I get a generic, unstyled 404 error message

Assuming your `ErrorDocument` directive is still set to serve `/404.html` and you are using relative paths in `/404.html`, then any relative URL-paths will naturally resolve relative to the `/parent` "directory", not the document root, as it would otherwise do if requesting `example.com/nonexistentpage.html`.

Remember it is the *browser* that resolves relative URLs, based on the URL being requested. This has nothing to do with the filesystem path on your server.

See this other related question for additional examples and discussion about the use of the `base` tag:

- [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Comment: Why wouldn't you advise using a base tag?  I use them frequently to solve problems like this.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, got it to work. Stephen how would you use a base tag to solve this problem? Maybe post another answer to my question if possible.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "unadvisable" maybe a bit strong. It's OK. (Although it is _better_ in most cases to use root-relative URLs if you are able to.) But you should be aware of some caveats... such as any _relative_ URL that is intended to target the _current_ document will now target the base URL. Such as in-page anchors `href="#top"` and `href="?sortby=date"` (less common) type URLs etc. These relative URLs that target the current document will need to be modified to include the full URL of the current page (which kind of defeats the point of using the `base` tag to begin with).

Comment: @heyycap I mention the use of the `base` tag in an answer to another question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243 - This other question relates to URL-rewriting, but the same principle applies here. In your question, the URL is effectively being rewritten to the error document. (In actual fact, it is an _internal subrequest_ that causes the error document to be served, but the result is similar).