# Multiple rules to rewrite the url

Tags: seo, htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Why both rules don't work together and how can i fix it? Only the first one works... I think that there's a conflict between the two rules, but i did not found a solution yet

`?p=` is the querystring i use to access the files that are into the main directory of my website, and `?page=` is for a sub-directory.

My current URLs are:

```
https://example.com/?p=home
https://example.com/?page=article
https://example.com/?page=article&tab=2
```

And i want it to become:

```
https://example.com/home
https://example.com/article
https://example.com/article/2
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: (I'm sure I've seen the exact same question somewhere else recently, but I can't seem to find it?!)

Comment: Your rewrite rules won't know if a file is in the directory or the subdirectory.   It might be simpler to put all your pages into one directory.  Otherwise you'll have to make a list of pages in one of the directories in your rewrite rules.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Your title edit doesn't seem correct. They appear to be arbitrarily wanting to rewrite some "first path segments" to `?p=` and some "first path segments" to `?page=`. That's the primary conflict that needs resolving before the additional `tab` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have a conflict.

- Both your `.htaccess` rules have exactly the same conditions, so the first one is always going to win. The second is never going to be executed.
- Your URL structure is ambiguous.

You need to take a step back, before trying to write any code, how would *you* resolve the following URLs:

- `https://example.com/home`
- `https://example.com/article`
- `https://example.com/foo`

How do you know that `home` should resolve to `?p=home` and `article` should resolve to `?page=article`? What about `foo`? You can only "see" what's in the URL.

You need to either:

- Have some discernible difference between the URLs, so you know how to rewrite it. For example: `example.com/p/home` vs `example.com/pg/home`
- If the number of URLs rewritten to `?p=` (or `?page=`) is limited then you can literally list the URL patterns in your directive. And everything else goes to `?page=` (or `?p=`). For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(home|about)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
  :
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
  ```
- Rewrite *everything* to a single URL parameter (eg. `?page=`) and decide in your PHP how the page should be served. This would seem to be the more logical solution since you are rewriting to `index.php` in both scenarios anyway and you don't want to keep having to edit `.htaccess`. This could also handle the additional `tab` "parameter".

**The additional "tab" parameter**

If all URLs that have a second path segment should be rewritten to `?page=` then that could be a "discernable" difference. However, that currently fails when the second path segment is omitted, as in `/article`. How should this be handled?

> the files to `?page=` are into a sub-directory, and the URL could be this: `https://example.com/news-folder/article`

Your question made no reference to a subdirectory. This would be enough to differentiate the "type" of URLs and to be able to rewrite the URLs differently.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Stop processing if the request looks like it maps to a physical resource
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:gif|jpg|png|css|js)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Single path segment rewrite to ?p=
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

# Requests for files in the subdirectory rewrite to ?page=
RewriteRule ^news-folder/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

# Requests for files in the subdirectory with additional numeric "tab"
RewriteRule ^news-folder/([^/]+)/(\d+)$ index.php?page=$1&tab=$2 [L]
```

The last two rules could be combined if you are OK having an empty `tab` parameter. eg. `example.com/news-folder/article` would be rewritten `example.com/index.php?page=article&tab=`. As it stands, the directives are separate, so the `tab` parameter is not present at all when `/2` (for example) is not appended.

**UPDATE:** The filesystem checks (for static resources and to prevent a rewrite loop) could be omitted entirely if you are more restrictive with the regex you use to target your article pages. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Single path segment rewrite to ?p=
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

# Requests for files in the subdirectory rewrite to ?page=
RewriteRule ^news-folder/([^/.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

# Requests for files in the subdirectory with additional numeric "tab"
RewriteRule ^news-folder/([^/.]+)/(\d+)$ index.php?page=$1&tab=$2 [L]
```

This just means that your URLs to your pages cannot contain `.` (dot). You could be more restrictive and only allow word characters (plus hyphen) and change `[^/.]+` to `[\w-]+`. This then allows article names that only consist of the characters: `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` and `-`.

You can make the subdirectory `/news-folder` entirely generic and match any subdirectory. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^\w+/(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Now, any request for `/<something>/article` would be rewritten to `index.php?page=article`.

Comment: So you meant that it's impossible to use a friendly url to more than 1 querystring? The number of URLs to `?p=` is limited, and i can list it on the directive as you said, but to `?page=` the URLs is not limited. You asked me how could i have a "discernable" difference between the URLs, the files to `?page=` are into a sub-directory, and the URL could be this: `https://example.com/news-folder/article`. Could it be possible to use a friendly URL to both querystrings? Sadly i don't think i can rewrite everything to a single URL paramenter...

Comment: It's impossible if there is nothing to differentiate the URLs. Only the URLs to one would need to be limited, everything else would rewrite to the other parameter (I've updated my example). "the files to `?page=` are into a sub-directory" - the example(s) in your question do not show a subdirectory. If that is the case then that completely changes your question. Yes, that is enough to differentiate the URLs.

Comment: I did not put anything about the sub-directory on my examples because it was working fine, but only one rewriterule as i said. Could you tell me what i'm doing wrong? https://pastebin.com/hMaAtV4M This return a `Error 500`.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: The  `:` is not literal - that is pseudo-code, indicating that directives are omited.

Comment: The 500 error is because `:` by itself is invalid.

Comment: "I did not put anything about the sub-directory on my examples" - but don't your actual URLs contain the subdirectory? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Finally i solved this thanks a lot! No my URLs don't contain the sub-directory, i was able to access them only using the querystring.

Comment: About the `?page=` everything is working fine, unless one thing, the css files is not loading on `/news-folder/article/2..3..4..etc` only loads on `/news-folder/article`, i have checked the file path and it's correct, i also made some tests, the css only loads if i put it on a `style` tag on this file. That's really strange, do you have any idea why it's happening?

Comment: I also realized that the css only loads on `/news-folder/article/2..3..4..etc` if i use this file path `../../css.style.css` and on `/news-folder/article` it will be `../css.style.css` I actually can use a absolute url on it `example.com/css/style.css` but it will be good to know why i need to put more one `../` on the path

Comment: It looks like you are using relative URL-paths to your CSS. See this question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css "checked the file path and it's correct" - make sure that _what the browser sees_ is correct.