# htaccess 404 code does not trap an incorrect URL path (with a / in the string

Tags: htaccess, 404

I have a simple 404 redirect in my `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /404.htm

ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hypnosis-retreat.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

When I enter the domain `https://example.co.uk/bhabha` it correctly renders the 404 page. Where I enter the URL `https://example.co.uk/bhabha/morebhabha` it fails to render the 404 page correctly.

I need to trap a path that goes nowhere.

Comment: The 404 document is being correctly called, it's just not being "rendered" correctly (as you say) - missing stylesheets and images. This is because you are using relative URLs to all your static resources (images, CSS, JS. etc.). You need to use root-relative (or absolute) URLs in your error document HTML. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the linked question that discusses this in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think that happens because you have relative paths to your CSS/JS/IMG assets. Hence although the 404 loads the correct page, it cannot load the correct files when you try to access a URL outside of root level.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply which I understand. The website in question uses a code generator and therefore not best suited to changing the code manually. I could place the Base Tag in the 404.htm page only. Do you think that would resolve the issue? Thanks

Comment: @GaryLowrey Using the `base` tag is a solution, but note the caveats as mentioned in [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the linked question above. However, these issues are less likely to apply to a 404 error document, so you are probably OK. Give it a go and test it!

Comment: @MrWhite - thank you. I used a <base href= "https://hypnosis-retreat.co.uk/">  and updated the htaccess to "ErrorDocument 404 https://hypnosis-retreat.co.uk/404.htm". There was only an email link on the 404 page and all works well now.

Comment: @GaryLowrey You shouldn't change the `ErrorDocument` directive - that was already correct. By changing that to an absolute URL it will now trigger a 302 redirect to your 404 page (which may not respond with a 404 status). By redirecting to your error document you probably negate the need for a `base` tag - but "redirecting" to the error document is "bad" (for users and SEO).

Comment: @MrWhite - thank you. Understood