# Internal Server Error caused by rewriting

Tags: htaccess, php, mod-rewrite

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]



# External redirect from "/post.php?id=<num>" to "/post/<num>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ /post/%1 [R=301,L]

# Internal rewrite from "/post/<num>" to "/post.php?id=<num>"
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is my .htaccess, and I get 500 error, or internal server error. i have tried to use it without the if and it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the URL(s) you are requesting and your general URL format. For instance, do your URLs contain dots? Knowing your filesystem structure could also be helpful. What is the intention behind these directives - notably that last part?

Comment: Have you tried removing all the rules and them putting them back one at a time until you discover which is causing problems?

Comment: the one that cause the error is the one that remove .HTML & .PHP from the links . i need all of them works in same time

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several places in the code you've posted that could trigger a "500 error" (or *rewrite-loop*), depending on the URL being requested (which you've not stated) and the filesystem structure (which you've not stated).

However, the following directive is your most immediate concern:

> ```
> RewriteRule . /post.php
> ```

This will result in a rewrite-loop for any request that is not rewritten to a `.html` or `.php` file by the previous rules.

You may be able to resolve the "rewrite-loop" by simply removing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string, to make it a filesystem path, rather than a URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteRule . post.php
```

However, that still isn't necessarily correct, as you are rewriting "everything", including any static resources, so this is unlikely to work as intended. What is the intention here? What are you trying to do?

The directive that follows is also in the wrong order and you should be rewriting directly to `post.php` (with the `.php` extension), rather than relying on further rewrites to complete the request.

> **UPDATE:** im trying to show posts like this : localhost/post/1 not like the current : localhost/post.php?id=1

If that is *all* you are trying to do then you don't need most of the directives currently in your `.htaccess` file.

Assuming you are already correctly linking to the *canonical* URL, eg. `/post/1` and not the old URL `/post.php?id=1` then all you need is the following:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Internal rewrite from "/post/<num>" to "/post.php?id=<num>"
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Since your URL `/post` maps to the file `/post.php` (ie. same basename, without the extension) then you need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled (ie. `Options -MultiViews`).

If you are changing an existing URL structure that has already been indexed by the search engines and linked to by third parties then you can *optionally* redirect from the old URL to the new in order to preserve SEO. (But this has nothing to do with making your site "work", since you are already correctly linking to the canonical URL.)

However, you need to be careful of a redirect-loop, hence the need for an additional condition to ensure we only redirect direct requests, not rewritten requests.

For example:

```
# External redirect from "/post.php?id=<num>" to "/post/<num>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ /post/%1 [R=301,L]
```

This should go *before* the internal rewrite directive above.

Note: Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues. 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser, so can make testing problematic.

### Summary (Version 1)

With these directives in place, the entire `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# External redirect from "/post.php?id=<num>" to "/post/<num>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ /post/%1 [R=301,L]

# Internal rewrite from "/post/<num>" to "/post.php?id=<num>"
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

---

### UPDATE:

> okay it worked, but it dosent show the css...

As noted in comments, this is most probably due to using relative URL-paths to your CSS files in your HTML source. If you are rewriting the URL to different path depths then you need to use root-relative or absolute URLs to your static resources.

For example, if you call your CSS with the relative URL `styles.css`, then from `/post.php?id=123` the *browser* will look for `/styles.css`, but from `/post/123` it will look for `/post/styles.css`.

See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the [following Webmasters question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css) that goes into more detail about this.

> also it doesn't have the rule that remove the `.php` and `.HTML` format from the link. i want it also to remove `.php` / `.HTML` from links.

To clarify, these rules "add back" the `.php` (or `.html`) extension that has already been removed in your HTML link. These directives don't "remove" anything.

Your current rules are in the wrong order - they should come *after* the above rewrite (this would avoid the 500 error on URLs like `/post/1`). However, they are incorrect and will result in a rewrite-loop (500 error) for certain URL requests, since the check for the existence of the `.php` (or `.html`) file is not necessarily the same as the file you are rewriting to.

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the [following ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error) that goes into more detail and explains this at length.

So, instead of the following:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
> ```

The directives to add back the `.html` extension should be more like this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

Additional notes:

- No need to check that the request does not map to a directory before checking that the request *with* `.html` maps to a file. The two checks are (or should be) mutually exclusive.
- No need to backslash escape the literal dot in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* - since this not a regex; the dot has no special meaning here.
- No need for the `^` and `$` anchors on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, since regex is greedy by default.
- The `NC` flag is not required since you are already matching *everything*.
- It could be optimised further by only rewriting requests that don't already have a `.html` extension. Or don't have any extension at all? (Or perhaps redirect such requests to the canonical URL?)

## Final Summary

Bringing all these code blocks together we have the following:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# External redirect from "/post.php?id=<num>" to "/post/<num>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ /post/%1 [R=301,L]

# Internal rewrite from "/post/<num>" to "/post.php?id=<num>"
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

# Append ".html" if the HTML file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]

# Append ".php" if the PHP file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Didnt work. im trying to show posts like this :
localhost/post/1
not like the current : 
localhost/post.php?id=1

Comment: Have you changed your internal links to use a URL of the form `/post/1`? If that is all you want to do then most of the directives in your `.htaccess` file would seem to be redundant!?

Comment: no i did not its not form , its just link to show posts.. not a form.

Comment: "form", meaning "format"... do your links look like `/post/1` in your HTML source code?

Comment: Assuming you are already correctly linking to the canonical URL - I've updated my answer.

Comment: okay it worked, but it dosent show the css also it doesn't have the rule that remove the .php and .HTML format from the link. i want it also to remove .php / .HTML from links..

Comment: "it dosent show the css" - that will happen if you are using _relative_ URL-paths to your CSS files. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the [following Webmasters question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css) that goes into detail about this.

Comment: "it doesn't have the rule that remove the .php and .HTML format from the link" - You didn't state this was a requirement in your "comment" above. You simply mentioned about `/post/1` URLs, which does not require those other directives (in the way I've rewritten it). It's also a little unusual to require both `.html` and `.php` rules on the same site. Incidentally, those directives don't "remove" the file extension - they actually "add it back" - it should already have been "removed" in your original link.

Comment: If the extensionless `.html` and `.php` URLs are a requirement then I can include these rules in my answer. But note that the rules you had posted are not strictly correct and could also result in 500 errors (ie. rewrite-loops) under certain conditions.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the additional points raised here.