# .htaccess -- Trailing slash and characters after file extension

Tags: htaccess

I've got some weird usability warnings popping up in my search console for pages which don't actually exist on my site. It looks like someone is creating 100's of malformed links to my pages.

Here's the problem.

Say I have `https://example.com/pagename.html`

Someone is creating hundreds of links with random text *after the filetype* like this: `https://example.com/pagename.html/randomtext`

Strangely, with that malformed URL, part of the page renders, but renders with broken styling for some reason. (Triggering search console warnings for every one of those "pages"). I'm not really sure how or why these broken URLs are rendering at all. My understanding is that this should return a 404 error. But it doesn't.

So...

I'm trying to solve the problem with .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

That sort of works. It removes the trailing slash from `https://example.com/pagename.html/` but it doesn't fix `https://example.com/pagename.html/randomchars`

How do I get it to ignore all characters following the file type? (except standard GET strings starting with a ?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "`/pagename.html`" - is `pagename.html` a real file? Does it really have a `.html` file extension?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, the extension .html is real. Your answer below was awesome btw. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

The regex `^(.+)/$` only matches URLs that end with a slash, so it matches `/pagename.html/`, but not `/pagename.html/randomchars`.

However, to avoid matching the slash anywhere in the URL (you probably have multiple path segments in some of your URLs) you can specifically match the file extension `.html`. This also negates the need for the directory check.

For example, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)/ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note the absence of the trailing end-of-string anchor (`$`) on the regex.

I made the regex non-greedy (ie. the `?` in `.+?`) so that it matches the *first* instance of `.html` in the URL-path and not the last. Otherwise, if the "randomchars" also contained an instance of `.html/` then you'd potentially get just another broken request/redirect.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. Only use a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure everything is working OK.

> I'm not really sure how or why these broken URLs are rendering at all.

If `pagename.html` is a real file then the trailing `/randomchars` are *additional pathname information* (path-info) on the URL. Whether Apache accepts path-info on the URL or whether it triggers a 404 is (by default) dependent on the handler that manages the file type (`.html`, `.php`, etc.). Although the handler for `.html` files usually rejects path-info by default, unless you've explicitly enabled it or are parsing `.html` files as PHP or something?

If this is indeed *path-info* (as described above) then you could instead disable path-info for all file types:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

If you then remove the redirect (`RewriteRule` directive) above then such URLs will generate a 404 as intended. If you keep the redirect then the redirect will still occur.

> with that malformed URL, part of the page renders, but renders with broken styling for some reason.

The broken styling (failure to load CSS) is most probably due to using relative URL-paths to your CSS files. With the additional path segment(s) on the URL (ie. path-info), you are changing the base URL that the relative URL is *relative* to. eg. A relative URL of the form `css/mystyles.css` will resolve to `/pagename.html/css/mystyles.css` instead of `/css/mystyles.css` as is probably intended, so results in a 404 and no styles are rendered. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question for more information on this: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Comment: If I could vote you up 20 times I would. Thank you for this awesome answer. And yes, the path to CSS was relative. That makes perfect sense. Also fixed now. Thank you!

Comment: Also: Yes, as you guessed, I have .php parsing enabled in .html pages.

Comment: "If I could vote you up 20 times I would", wasn't enough praise already? ;) Everything worked perfectly, thanks again! EDIT: Ah.. sorry didn't accept the answer. My bad. Just did.