# Is there a way to set up a redirect in htaccess to convert a folder/paths to a params

Tags: htaccess, 302-redirect

After trawling through posts I have this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.software$
RewriteRule ^downloads$ https://example.software\?mode\=downloads&%{QUERY_STRING}  [R=302,L]
```

This works fine to convert

```
example.software/downloads?name=bing
```

to

```
example.software?mode=downloads&name=bing
```

And I could make that work, but what I really want is to convert

```
example.software/downloads/bing
```

to

```
example.software?mode=downloads&name=bing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.software$
> RewriteRule ^downloads$ https://example.software\?mode\=downloads&%{QUERY_STRING}  [R=302,L]
> ```

This is an external redirect. The URL is changed to `/?mode=downloads&name=bing` - which is what the user will see. The idea of implementing a "friendly" URL like `/downloads/bing` is so this is the *only* URL that the user sees and the underlying file path that actually handles the request is hidden from the user. If you are going to "redirect" the request to the "ugly" URL (the file path that handles the request) then there is not much point in implementing the "friendly" URL to begin with (except maybe for "sharing").

(You are also unnecessarily backslash-escaping `?` and `=` in the *substitution* string - this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex. There should also be a slash after the hostname if you are *redirecting*.)

I'm assuming that the file that actually handles the request is `index.php` in the document root.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.software$
RewriteRule ^(downloads)/([^/]+)$ index.php?mode=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

This *internally rewrites* (the URL in the browser does not change) a request for `example.software/downloads/bing` to `/index.php?mode=downloads&name=bing`.

`$1` and `$2` are backreferences to the first and second capturing groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. `$1` is always `downloads`, but `$2` is whatever  is in the second path segment.

The URL in the browser's address bar remains as `/downloads/bing`, but your `index.php` script is called with the `mode` and `name` URL (GET) parameters.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working at all.  If I dont have the nested folder name, then I get a listing of the directory **downloads**.  Which is good, because **cpanel** was misleading me into thinking  as no-indexing.  I have fixed that now - so it gives a 403

Comment: What happens exactly when you request `/downloads/bing`? An error? Undesirable response? Unstyled page? Nothing? This rule will only rewrite `/downloads/<something>`, it won't rewrite `/downloads` (or `/downloads/`) - which would be problematic since downloads is also a physical directory. If you request `/index.php?mode=downloads&name=bing` directly does it work? I'm assuming your script is named `index.php` - is that correct?

Comment: The file is index.html itself, and I had changed the **index.php** to **index.html**.  If I type in **?mode=downloads&name=bing**, the code detects it and displays it (for now).  But if I type **/downloads/bing**, it runs the index.html but doesnt run the **javascript** in it.

Comment: But if I change it to external reference  **RewriteRule ^(downloads)/([^/]+)$ https://example.com?mode=$1&name=$2 [L]**  Then it works

Comment: It sounds like you are using relative links/URLs to your JavaScript files. You need to use root-relative (or absolute) URLs. See this related Webmasters question: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Comment: @RohitGupta "It doesnt seem to be working at all." - to clarify, the rewrite itself is probably working OK, but relative links in the HTML source (as mentioned above) is the "problem" now.