# How to use mod-rewrite for SEO friendly get params?

Tags: seo, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

At present the webpage accepts get params like this ***https://TripTale.in /details.php?id=AlphaNumericKeys***
Which I want to make it look like ***https://TripTale.in /details/someTexts/AlphaNumericKeys***

Contents of my .htaccess file

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?tripTale\.in)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? /404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^details/(.*)$ details.php?q=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^details/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$    details.php?id=$1&title=$2

RewriteRule ^details/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ /details.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

All the above tried code does not works and shows error 404.
However the below code works but makes all the images file as blank.

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?tripTale\.in)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? /404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .? /404.php

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+) details.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: I recommend putting your database keys closer to the front of your URLs.  Long URLs have a tendency to get truncated by emails and when displayed in other sites.  When the db key is near the front, you can usually redirect to the full URL from a truncated URL.  When the id is at the end, that isn't usually possible.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "I recommend putting your database keys closer to the front of your URLs"- That "kind of" looks like what they have done in the last rule that supposedly "works"? However...

Comment: "the below code works" - Except that I can't see how that would "work" at all? It doesn't match the example URL you posted and the preceding rule(s) would first rewrite the request to `/404.php` so the final rule is never processed? Where have you put the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: "but makes all the images file as blank" - usually an indication you are (erroneously) using relative URL-paths to your images (and possibly other static assets). See: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? /404.php [L]
```

Shouldn't those three lines be just one: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

You may end up using that statement to direct to details.php instead

```
RewriteRule ^details/(.*)$ details.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

`details.php` is looking for `q`? Not `id` as in `details.php?id=AlphaNumericKeys`?

I have been wanting to learn more about this technique and recently bookmarked a page that may be helpful to you.
[[HOWTO] Rewrite all urls to one index.php in Apache](https://gist.github.com/RaVbaker/2254618)

> the below code works but makes all the images file as blank

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+) details.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA]`

That's because you are rewriting *everything*. `details/someTexts/AlphaNumericKeys` becomes `details.php?id=details&title=someTexts/AlphaNumericKeys` and `images/graphic.png` becomes `details.php?id=images&title=graphic.png`